# Do you have a vowel trapezoid for Spanish?

Tags: phonetics, reference-request, spanish

I am trying to contrast the vowel systems of English and Spanish, and showing two vowel trapezoids seems like a good approach. I've not yet found one yet. Any ideas?

Comment: [Section 3.3 of *How Language Works*](http://www.indiana.edu/~hlw/PhonUnits/vowels.html) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: That's a good resource. It's important to recognize, however, that, while the Spanish non-low vowel phonemes /i e o u/ use tense vowel symbols -- and are normally tense in open syllables -- they have lax allophones in closed syllables. This is why Spanish speakers have so much trouble with the English tense-lax vowel constrasts like _sheep_ and _ship_; Spanish doesn't use tense vowels in closed syllables, nor lax vowels in open ones.

Comment: @jlawler, your comment confuses me. To me, tenseness is a phonemic concept, but in Spanish tenseness is not phonemic. Anyway, assuming you mean that vowel phonemes are realized differently in open and closed syllables in Spanish, do you have any support for that statement? While I think it might be true for certain dialects, I've never heard that about (or noticed it in) standard Castilian (as spoken in Spain).

Comment: There are more than two allophones, of course, but tenseness is indeed phonetic; it has to do with the tension in the muscle bundles at the root of the tongue. This can be demonstrated easily. In Spanish tenseness is not phonemic, and therefore is not recognized, just like English speakers never notice the [i] at the end of _eh_ /e/, because it's automatic. As for sources, googling "Spanish vowel allophone lax tense" turned up [this](http://sanders.phonologist.org/Papers/corbin-thesis.pdf), among others. At the bottom of p. 6 there's a statement that Spanish laxes vowels in closed syllables.

Comment: @jlawler, FWIW, the wikipedia article about tenseness (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenseness) agrees with me: "Some languages like Spanish are often considered as having only tense vowels, but since the quality of tenseness is not a phonemic feature in this language, it cannot be applied to describe its vowels in any meaningful way." The paper you link to looks interesting, but talks about Eastern Andalusian in particular, so I'm curious whether anything similar can be said for Spanish in general.

Comment: @dainichi, _any_ phonetic feature may be phonemic in some languages and not in others. What you've quoted says that tenseness is not phonemic in Spanish, which is what John Lawler said.

Answer (score 3):

I've made the trapezium from Otavio Macedo's comment in LaTeX and uploaded it [here](http://pdfcast.org/pdf/spanish-vowel-trapezium). It looks a little nicer now, and you can copy, save or snip it. Here is a preview:

[image]

Comment: I added the image to the answer itself, if you don't mind.

Comment: Not at all. Thank you

Comment: If you want to re-use the image and change the symbols, you can use the `vowel` and `tipa` packages in LaTeX. You can find my example of the code and the result [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/515d38bd341987d1131f4641).

Comment: @KleinePrins does the vowel package create vowel trapeziums automatically? I don't see anything else in the code that would make the structure. You could use tikz and draw some arrows within the vowel environment to show diphthongs if you wanted to as well, I take it?

Comment: @DangerFourpence Yes, it does, thanks to the `vowel` environment. However, the [package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/vowel) explains a few options to get different diagrams but no more than that. Do you mean arrows for diphtongs like [this](http://www.yorku.ca/earmstro/ipa/diphthongs.html)? Then I think you should use TikZ instead of `vowel` for the whole diagram.

Comment: @KleinePrins Very handy. Yes, vectors like in the link. It's a shame the package doesn't account for that. I might upload one for diphthongs if I have the time.

Comment: @DangerFourpence I hope you do. It would be a great tool for linguists using LaTeX.

Comment: @DangerFourpence Update: I found an improvement to the `vowel` package. This one allows drawing arrows inside the chart! [Source](http://www.tug.org/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pst-vowel/pst-vowel.pdf)

Comment: It would be good to include the TeX source code, which would make it easier for other people to modify this image as required.

Comment: @TRiG you're probably right. But I don't have the source code any more.